# Find 5 consecutive row values in Pandas Dataframe that are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe of the format

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
Time1  a  Match
Time2  b  NaN
Time3  c  Match
Time4  d  Match
Time5  e  Match
Time6  f  Match
Time7  g  Match
Time8  h  NaN
Time9  i  Match
Time10 j  NaN
```

So, for the data frame I would like to find the values from Time3 to Time7 as the Col3 is having Match Values for 5 consecutive rows.

I tried using rolling window,

```
idx = (df['Col3'].rolling(window=5) == "Match")
```

But according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), it seems like it is made for calculations rather than Direct comparison

Is there any other optimized way to go about it?

Comment: what about 6 consecutive match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One classical way is to use boolean indexing with a custom mask. Breaking it down, it relies on making groups of consecutive Match values, and counting the group size to slice the matching rows.

```
m = df.groupby(df['Col3'].ne('Match').cumsum())['Col3'].transform('size').ge(5)
df[m&m.shift()]
```

Alternatively:

```
m = df['Col3'].ne('Match')
m2 = df.groupby((m|m.shift()).cumsum())['Col3'].transform('size').ge(5)
df[m2]
```

output:

```
    Col1 Col2   Col3
2  Time3    c  Match
3  Time4    d  Match
4  Time5    e  Match
5  Time6    f  Match
6  Time7    g  Match
```

Comment: This works great!
How can I also quickly get the number of groups?